# FileCopyUtils Springframework

Tags: spring, file-copying

I want to copy a file using spring FileCopyUtils.
this is the first time I used
I followed a tutorial and I get this exception

```
package com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.integration.repositories.foo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;

public class CopyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
            IOException {

        File source = new File("‪C:\\Users\\Momo Kh\\Desktop\\CV.pdf");
        File dest = new File("C:\\Users\\Momo Kh\\Desktop\\Test\\CV.pdf");
        FileCopyUtils.copy(source, dest);

    }

}
```

And i have this Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪C:\Users\Momo Kh\Desktop\CV.pdf (La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:63)
    at com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.integration.repositories.foo.CopyTest.main(CopyTest.java:15)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code works (The same as the last with some change) 
I think it was a bug

```
package com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.integration.repositories.foo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;

public class CopyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
            IOException {

        File source = new File("C:\\Users\\Momo Kh\\Desktop\\CV.pdf");
        File dest = new File("C:\\Users\\Momo Kh\\Desktop\\files\\destfile1.pdf");


        long start = System.nanoTime();
        long end;

        // copy file using Spring FileCopyUtils
        start = System.nanoTime();
        FileCopyUtils.copy(source, dest);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Time taken by Spring FileCopyUtils Copy = " + (end - start));



    }

}
```

And the result

```
Time taken by Spring FileCopyUtils Copy = 41100377
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you don't have the file or you don't have the necessary priviliges to touch it. Try some directory like `C:\\Momo Kh\\CV.pdf` instead. Maybe you can't access stuff under user.

Comment: it's the same execption

Comment: can you try this after creating the necessary folders and files:

File source = new File("‪C:/Momo/CV.pdf");
File dest = new File("C:/Momo/Test/CV.pdf");
FileCopyUtils.copy(source, dest);

Comment: Sorry but it still rise rhe same execption.